# c# Reading source code with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

My code is as below. But I am getting error. How can I read the url source code in the example.
Error Message 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden'

CookieContainer cookierJar = new CookieContainer();

```
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.hepsiburada.com/dyson-v11-absolute-extra-kablosuz-supurge-dyson-turkiye-garantili-p-HBV00000W4W6U");

        webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        webRequest.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        webRequest.CookieContainer = cookierJar;
        webRequest.UserAgent = "My Thirsty Browser";

        int statusCode = 0;
        string sourceCode = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

            statusCode = (int)webResponse.StatusCode;

            StreamReader readContent = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
            sourceCode = readContent.ReadToEnd();

            webResponse.Close();
            webResponse = null;
        }
        catch (WebException xc)
        {
            if (xc.Response is HttpWebResponse)
            {
                HttpWebResponse rs = xc.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                StreamReader readContent = new StreamReader(rs.GetResponseStream());
                if (readContent != null)
                {
                    sourceCode = readContent.ReadToEnd();
                }

                statusCode = (int)rs.StatusCode;
            }
            else
            {
                statusCode = (int)xc.Status;
                sourceCode = xc.Message;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception xc)
        {
            sourceCode = xc.Message;
        }
```

Comment: I'm concerned about the ethics of the code you have posted.

Comment: Forbidden means Forbidden. That eCommerce site doesn't like screen scrapers and blocked you. They may be checking the Agent header or something else to determine whether a request comes from a bot or not. BTW all that code can be replaced with `HttpClient.GetStringAsync`

Comment: Is your code working if replace the Url with https://www.google.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I get a 403 in IE, I guess you need to be logged in to retrieve the resource. Your browser may have the credentials cached but your app isn't designed to log you in. Or are you logged in to Google in your browser - try logging out and see if you still have access....